# jquery ajax html issues with Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

so.. i got this issue with my code, i dont know what to do, because it actually works on Internet Explorer... it opens "fine" on chrome or mozilla, but when i want to go to the links in my menu, they just dont work! i click them and nothing happens!! Help me!

(my css code works fine because it was and old one I used, so Im sure it works)

this is my menu html

---

```
<head>
    <title> Pratica 5 </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
    content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function carga(pagina,menu){

            $.ajax({
               url : pagina,
               cache : false,
               success : function(object,status,response){

                  $("#principal").html(response.responseText);
               }
           });
           $("#menu div").removeClass('bActivo');
           $("#m"+menu).addClass('bActivo');
        }


   </script>
</head>



<body>
    <div id="mensaje" style="display:none" title="Holaa">
    welcome :3
    </div>


   <div id="area">
        <div id="menu">

            <div id="m1" onClick="javascript:carga('acerca.html',1)">Inicio</div> 

            <div id="m2"onClick="javascript:carga('pagina4.html',2)">Acerca: </div>

           <div id="m3"onClick="javascript:carga('ayuda.html',3)">Ayuda</div>

        </div>
        <div id="principal">


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: have you styled any of your div's with negative z-index css properties? This will cause links to malfunction.

Comment: seems fine in demo http://plnkr.co/edit/WuBQUH4kFSpf0XtSQOvK?p=preview

Comment: No no negative z-index.. sure of that... what else could it be ??? Im new at this and I only know ajax :( .. I dont get why does it work in Explorer and not in chrome!!! god!

Comment: checked out @Arun plunker, and when i click link, filename is shown, is that what you expect, if so then it works on my debian 6 chrome 19

Comment: @gwillie yes.... in those html files I just gave the filename as the content

Comment: yes, i went to plunker and the filename is shown,, so maybe is my browser???? how can i fix it ??? thank you so much @Arun

Comment: its just so weird!! why on earth will it work on Explorer!!! and not in Chrome!! >.< gooood!

Comment: @fefi if there are no errors in the browser console then as a testing step add some very simple contents to the dynamic content pages as I've done... then make sure that is working

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
success : function(object,status,response){
                  $("#principal").html(response.responseText);
               }
```

with this

```
success : function(data){
                  $("#principal").html(response.responseText);
               },error:function(xhr, status, error){
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);
               }
```

This is complete working code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function carga(pagina,menu){
//alert(pagina);
            $.ajax({
               url : pagina,
               cache : false,
               success : function(data){
                  $("#principal").html(response.responseText);
               },error:function(xhr, status, error){
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);
               }
           });
           $("#menu div").removeClass('bActivo');
           $("#m"+menu).addClass('bActivo');
        }


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mensaje" style="display:none" title="Holaa">
    welcome :3
    </div>


   <div id="area">
        <div id="menu">

            <div id="m1" onClick="carga('acerca.html',1);">Inicio</div> 

            <div id="m2"onClick="carga('pagina4.html',2);">Acerca: </div>

           <div id="m3"onClick="carga('ayuda.html',3);">Ayuda</div>

        </div>
        <div id="principal">


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working sir !! :(( Im so saaaad! maybe I got something bad with my chrome ???? or mozilla???? happens same thing, i click on any of my 3 links in menu and it does nothiiing T_T im gonna cry!

Comment: @fefi don't worry, just chill - try to track the flow of script. Check if function is calling onclick or not by alerting something in function. If not there there must be problem in your browser

Comment: where can i find your email ?? I only found your website! itcse.com ! So sorry, Im new >.< @BOSS